# Insert into JSON using JSONiq

Tags: json, zorba, jsoniq

We are writing a JSONiq query to insert new properties into a JSON and return the updated JSON from the query.

**Query:**

```
jsoniq version "1.0";
let $users := {
  "name" : "Deadbeat Jim",
  "address" : "1 E 161st St, Bronx, NY 10451",
  "risk tolerance" : "high"
} 
insert json {"status" : "credit card declined"} into $users
return $users
```

`users` holds the input json, we are trying to add one more property using JSONiq insert command, as mentioned in JSONiq documentation [here](http://www.jsoniq.org/docs/JSONiqExtensionToXQuery-usecases/html-single/index.html#update.example)

We are getting below exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: (no URI):13,1: static error [err:XPST0003]: invalid expression: syntax error, unexpected expression (missing comma "," between expressions?)
```

**Questions :**

1. Is the query correct ? if not, How to make it correct syntactically/logically ?
2. Are there any good resources available online for JSONiq with examples ?

Comment: It says the error is on line 13. Which line is this?

Comment: last line return $users

Comment: Should there be a `;` at the end of the previous line? (And maybe also the line before that.)

Comment: tried that but getting syntax error unexpected ";"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some more explanations:

The way JSONiq updates work is identical to the way XQuery updates work. JSONiq updates are **declarative**: a JSONiq update program returns, in addition to an empty sequence in the data model, what is called a **pending update list (PUL)**, which is a list of updates (deletions, replacements, renamings, insertions, etc) to be applied to some documents.

JSONiq update has snapshot semantics, meaning that **no side effects** occur during the evaluation of the main expression. Instead, *after* the PUL has been computed, the engine may propagate the changes specified by the PUL to underlying storage (such as a file on disk, or a document store).

A syntactically correct version of the question's example would be:

```
jsoniq version "1.0";
let $users := {
  "name" : "Deadbeat Jim",
  "address" : "1 E 161st St, Bronx, NY 10451",
  "risk tolerance" : "high"
} 
return insert json {"status" : "credit card declined"} into $users
```

However, in this case, the PUL returned contains changes against a JSON object created on the fly, in memory. The lifetime of this object is only that of the evaluation of the query, so that this program simply has no visible effect.

If the `collection` function is in some way mapped to a database in a document store like Couchbase or MongoDB (that is, if the engine is documented and configured to do this), the following query will semantically apply an update to this document store.

```
jsoniq version "1.0";
let $users := collection("users")[$$.name eq "Jim"]
return insert json {"status" : "credit card declined"} into $users
```

A *copy-modify-return* expression (also called transform expression like in XQuery, see other answer on this page) provides a way to apply changes in memory without losing them, and without any persistent storage. It:

- creates a JSON object (as a **copy** of another), or an XML node, etc
- modifies that object by applying the PUL obtained from the **modify** expression (important: this has no visible side effects, as only a copy is being modified)
- **return**s the modified copy.

For advanced users: in this case, the copy clause contains a constructor that builds a fresh object, so the optimizer can actually skip the copying.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to make it work json updates using JSONiq. We need to use copy-modify-return clauses:

```
jsoniq version "1.0";
copy $users := {
      "name" : "Deadbeat Jim",
      "address" : "1 E 161st St, Bronx, NY 10451",
      "risk tolerance" : "high"
} 
modify insert json {"status" : "credit card declined"} into $users
return $users
```

Hope this might helpful to someone